# Some part of Vue2 component's template does not render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue2 app (called 'renderer-app') with a component as its child (called 'section-renderer'), which in turn has a child component. In the parent component (section-renderer) I have a template option in which the multiple components are added to the parent component:

template:

```
<div>
    <component v-for="(item, index) in layoutArray" :is="item.template" :cardObj="item.cardObj" :key="item.id"></component>
    <!--the above component gets rendered as it should, but the rest of the template is not rendered-->
    <div class="parallax-container">
        <div class="parallax">
           <img src="./images/banner2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="advertisement-text-box">
            <p class="advertisement-header">some header</p>
            <p class="advertisement-text">some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I have shown above in the comment line, the child component gets rendered multiple times as it should, but the rest of the template which should be rendered once per parent component does not render.
Strangely enough, if I insert a **div with text in it** between the two, the rest of the template renders too. So this works (of course with an unwanted line):

template:

```
<div>
    <component v-for="(item, index) in layoutArray" :is="item.template" :cardObj="item.cardObj" :key="item.id"></component>
    <div>extra</div> <!--the extra div with text-->
    <div class="parallax-container">
        <div class="parallax"><img src="./images/banner2.jpg"></div>

        <div class="advertisement-text-box">
            <p class="advertisement-header">some header</p>
            <p class="advertisement-text">some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried various positioning of the div around the child component and the rest of the template, but none seemed to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any Vue warnings in the console? Can you show the template code for the child component? Perhaps you're missing a start or end tag in the child component template and the extra <div></div> fixes it.

Comment: I could actually find the problem. The template was rendered but somehow it was squeezed out due to CSS. I got it to show up with a width:100% inside the CSS file. thank you.